# Can we React Context when there is no child-parent components

Tags: reactjs, react-context

```js
<Aux>
        <div>
          <DateTimePicker
            onChange={this.onChange}
            value={this.state.date}
          />
        </div>
        <StartContext.Provider value={{ ...this.state.date}}>
          {this.props.children}
        </StartContext.Provider>
      </Aux>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
return (
            <Aux>
                <div className="bar">
                    <div className="start">
                        Start
                    </div>
                    <div className="date">
                        <StartDatePicker>
                            <StartDatePicker/>
                        </StartDatePicker>
                    </div>
                    <div className="start">
                        End
                    </div>
                    <div className="date">
                        <EndDatePicker />
                    </div>
                    {/* <button className="buttonposition" onClick={this.ChangeByHour}>Hour</button>
                    <button className="buttonposition" onClick={this.ChangeByShift}>Shift</button>
                    <button className="buttonposition" onClick={this.ChangeByDay}>Day</button>
                    <button className="buttonposition" onClick={this.ChangeByWeek}>Week</button>
                    <button className="buttonposition" onClick={this.ChangeByMonth}>Month</button> */}
                    <button className="buttonposition" onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>Apply</button>
                    <button class="button2">Overhead<CgDropOpacity /></button>
                </div>
            </Aux>
        )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Working on react js(Context API).there were 2 components startdatepicker & Calendar.
StartDatepicker component - in return()i am using  and <StartContext.Provider>{this.props.children}</StartContext.Provider>  .so in calendar component inside return i am writing 

..This is giving me 2 datepickers in my UI which i dont want.

how to solve this when there is no child parent connection with help of react context.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two components in your UI because you are using `StartDatePicker` as a child of itself.

```
<StartDatePicker>
    <StartDatePicker/>
</StartDatePicker>
```

`StartDatePicker` does not need to have children.  The inner one already does not have children.

However if there are no children, then there is no point to the `Context`.  A context makes it's `value` available to its children.  That's all it does.  So a context with no children does nothing.

You need to rethink the hierarchy of your components.  Which components need to access the value of your context?  Those need to be inside of the context `Provider`.

The `Provider` needs to be higher up in the component tree.  Instead of the `value` being just a date, the value can be an object with properties `date` and `setDate`.  `StartDatePicker` can then use the `setDate` function from the context to update the context `date`.

You can probably do this without using contexts at all.  Store the `date` as a `state` in your `Calendar` component and pass a `setDate` callback as a prop to `StartDatePicker`.